What is the MTU size of an application traversing a WAN link?
I have a WAN link with jumbo frame support set to 9216
This WAN link terminates on a Juniper MX480 and there is also a sub-tending EX4300 switch
I want to replace that WAN link with lower costs options from other carriers that don't support full 9216 but they support between 8000-9000
In order to determine if I can replace this 9216 link with lower cost options I need to know the maximum size of all the applications that are traversing this WAN link
How can I find the maximum MTU size of the applications traversing this WAN link?
We have SevOne, Flow Falcon and NetScout but cannot find how I can monitor the WAN link and report the largest MTU size of an application traversing the WAN link
When you set a router / switch MTU size to 9216, I would like to see what traffic across the WAN link is close to that top level 9216. If a frame is above 9216 it will be fragmented so the router/switch reports that as a frame fragmented. As such if frames over the WAN link are far below 9216 I would like to know what the maximum is so that I can lower the MTU size on the router / switch appropriately.

MTU is the term for the network layer/IP. You're likely asking about "maximum datagram/segment size for UDP/TCP", the general terms are PDU/SDU. Is fragmentation an issue? Applications are explicitly off topic here for being above the transport layer, see the [help/on-topic].

We cannot recommend products here, see the [help/on-topic]. And I think you're looking from the wrong direction - if there are TCP-based applications that actually utilize jumbo frames, they're most likely to work with standard, even undersized frames as well. You need to look at your software inventory and compile a list of requirements for your WAN link from that.
